# In VBA, how to convert filter to sql string where clause

Tags: ms-access, vba

Has anyone got a better way to do this? I want the users to be able to filter to a set of records, and then use a sql statement to do something to just the filtered records.

My code at the moment looks something like the following, and it works.  But I do wonder if there is any better (or other?) way to achieve this that could avoid the clunky Replace statement? I wondered if I could do it using a recordset instead, but unless I'm missing something, there's no way to do set operations over a recordset, I'd have to loop through the records individually to do that.

Any other suggestions?

```
Dim db As Database
Dim frm As Form
Dim sqlCmd As String
Dim filter As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set frm = Forms("frmReplen").Controls("FrmReplenSheet").Form
filter = Replace(frm.filter, "[FrmReplenSheet].", "")

sqlCmd = "UPDATE tblRCmDataSheetExtract " & _
    "SET Completed = 1 " & _
    "WHERE " & filter

db.Execute sqlCmd
```

Comment: And what is your filter? You can easily translate the expression to a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: That was the point - I wanted to translate the filters to a WHERE clause, but the filter will be set by a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you could do is to shorten your procedure. You could do something like this:

```
currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblRCmDataSheetExtract SET Completed = 1 WHERE " & Replace(Forms!frmReplen!FrmReplenSheet.Form.Filter, "[FrmReplenSheet].", "")
```

Or when you're running it from within frmReplen you could use

```
currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblRCmDataSheetExtract SET Completed = 1 WHERE " & Replace(Me.FrmReplenSheet.Form.Filter, "[FrmReplenSheet].", "")
```

or from within the subform "FrmReplenSheet":

```
currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblRCmDataSheetExtract SET Completed = 1 WHERE " & Replace(Me.Form.Filter, "[FrmReplenSheet].", "")
```

that puts your whole procedure into one single command. It's up to you if you like better readability or shorter procedures.

Comment: Thanks Dorian, I see where you're going with this. What I was really after was another approach entirely, hoping that there would be a function or something that I've overlooked, but I've drawn a blank.  Never mind, it did work, despite being inelegant :)